# ansible rsync or copy a randomly named file to a remote machine

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I am using ansible 2.1 to either rsync or copy a file from the host machine to a remote one.  The file is in a directory but has a random string as part of its name.  I have tried using **ls -d** to get the name via the shell command and tried to register this value but apparently, the syntax I am using is causing the role to fail.  Any thoughts on what I might be doing wrong?

```
---
- name: copying file to server 
- local_action: shell cd /tmp/directory/my-server/target/
- local_action: shell ls -d myfile*.jar
  register: test_build
- debug: msg={{ test_build.stdout }}
- copy: src=/tmp/directory/my-server/target/{{ test_build.stdout }}  dest=/home/ubuntu/ owner=ubuntu group=ubuntu mode=644 backup=yes
  become: true
  become_user: ubuntu 
  become_method: sudo
```

**exception**

```
fatal: [testserver]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "reason": "no action detected in task. This often indicates a misspelled module name, or incorrect module path.\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/home/user/test/roles/test-server/tasks/move.yml': line 2, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n---\n- name: transferring file to server\n  ^ here\n\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/home/user/test/roles/test-server/tasks/synchronize.yml': line 2, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n---\n- name: transferring artifact to server\n  ^ here\n"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to simplify your commands. You also do not want to put a hyphen before a module name. This will cause a syntax error as it won't be able to identify that module as an action. You can only invoke one module per task. For example, this will not work;

```
- name: task one
  copy: src=somefile dest=somefolder/
  copy: src=somefile2 dest=somefolder2/
```

The two would need to be split into two separate tasks. The same for your playbook. Do the following:

```
  - name: copying file to server 
    local_action: "shell ls -d /tmp/directory/my-server/target/myfile*.jar"
    register: test_build
  - debug: msg={{ test_build.stdout }}

  - name: copy the file
    copy: src={{ test_build.stdout }}  dest=/home/ubuntu/ owner=ubuntu group=ubuntu mode=644 backup=yes
```

If possible, insert "become" in your playbook not in your tasks/main.yml file, unless you only want to use become for these two tasks and will be adding more tasks to the same playbook later on.

**Note**: The debug msg line is completely optional. It doesn't affect the results of the playbook in any way, all it will do is show you the folder/file name that was found as a result of the shell "ls" command.

Comment: thanks @avalon - will try and get back.  You are fantastic!

Answer (score 2):

You should avoid `shell` commands if possible, it is Ansible anti-pattern.
In your case you can use `fileglob` [lookup](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_lookups.html#more-lookups) like follows:

```
- name: Copy file 
  copy:
    src: "{{ lookup('fileglob','/tmp/directory/my-server/target/myfile*.jar', wantlist=true) | first }}"
    dest: /home/ubuntu/
    owner: ubuntu
    group: ubuntu
    mode: 644
    backup: yes
```

If you 100% sure that there is only one such file, you can omit `wantlist=true` and `| first` – I used it as a safe net to filter only first entry, if there are many.

Comment: spaciba @Konstantin - very useful

Comment: the lookup works for one of my cases where I need to run this locally - but I think it will not work if it needs to run on a remote machine - any thoughts on what would be the correct way of doing that on a remote machine (else I'll resort to the shell with ls -d)

Comment: You use `local_action` in the question, so `lookup` is a preferred way. If you want this on remote machine, you should use `find` module and register search result.

Comment: spaciba Konstantin